# Display tooltips

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform and I want to display a tooltip on hover/click when you click/hover over a information box.

I did look into [Qtip](https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip) but it was way to buggy and not well done so I have decided to go another way but I'm still not sure if a module is necessary for this or if I should write a script for it?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Form Tips](https://www.drupal.org/project/formtips) module.  I've tried this module and it's working fine for Webforms too.

> Form Tips module uses JS to move form descriptions to tooltips.
>
> It helps to reduce form clutter by removing form descriptions from the page and only displaying them when needed

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks good, is it stable tho to use on a production website?

Comment: @user2945872 Yes it seems. Maintenance status: Actively maintained,Development status: Under active development and has recommended release

Comment: @user2945872 You're welcome :)

Comment: The problem about formtips module is that it enable in the entire website, which to me seem kinda weird if you only want to enable it one place.